# Overloading function call operator and assignment

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In a project of mine, I'm writing a wrapper for `std::vector`. I'm doing this because I am using homogeneous coordinates and for some operations it's just easier to temporarily 'forget' the fourth coordinate.

Now I stumbled upon a problem. I have loads of assignments like the following:

```
    Vector v;
    v(0) = 5;
    v(1) = 6;
```

and so on. I also want to do the following:

```
   double x;
   x = v(0);
```

For that last thing, I can overload the () operator, but how would implement the first thing? (the zero and one being an index).

Comment: It sounds like there's little reason to use `std::vector` at all in your case. Despite its name, it has nothing to do with the vectors used in geometry or computer graphics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just return reference.

```
class Vector
{
  int data[4];
  int & operator() (int index) { return data[index]; }
};
```

Comment: Don't forget a `const` overload.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I discovered it myself a minute ago. Seems I tried everything but missed this. Ah well, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Return a non-const reference to the element to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Two things-

1. You should probably be overloading `operator[]` to do this rather than `operator()`, since it's the more natural operator here.  `operator()` is used to create function objects, while `operator[]` is the operator meaning "pick out the element at this position."
2. You can support assignment to the result of `operator[]` / `operator()` by having the function return a reference to the value that should be written to.  As a simple example, here's some code that represents a class wrapping a raw array:

(code here:)

```
class Array {
public:
    int& operator[] (unsigned index);
    int  operator[] (unsigned index) const;

private:
    int array[137];
};

int& Array::operator[] (unsigned index) {
    return array[index];
}
int Array::operator[] (unsigned index) const {
    return array[index];
}
```

The second of these functions is a `const` overload so you can have `const Array` read but not write values.

Comment: Yeah, when I was writing this code I was thinking about the c++faqslite explanation why you should use () instead of [] for a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

In the standard libraries, such things are implemented by having `operator()` (well, actually usually `operator[]`) return type `double &`. By returning a reference to a double, you can assign to or from it.

However, are you sure you want to wrap this around `std::vector`? This class is not a vector in the mathematical sense; it's much like a Java `ArrayList`, and so not at all efficient for small structures. Usually when I'm writing my own vector classes I'm planning on having lots of them around, so I implement a class from scratch on top of a static array.